# How to remove unwanted panels inside InspectorControls from core blocks in Gutenberg

Tags: plugin-development, filters, block-editor

If I want to extend the core block I can use [Block Filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters) where I found a filter like [`editor.BlockEdit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit).

Example from doc:

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;
 
const withInspectorControls = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody>My custom control</PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, 'withInspectorControl' );
 
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'my-plugin/with-inspector-controls',
    withInspectorControls
);
```

It works, but now i would like to **remove** unwanted panels from core blocks. Unfortunately, the documentation does not contain any such example so I can't understand how to do this.

So how to remove unwanted panels inside InspectorControls from core blocks in Gutenberg?

*Note: I know about the newest feature [`theme.json`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/25/introducing-theme-json-in-wordpress-5-8/), but it has very limited functions and won't remove everything it needs*